# Actionscript 3 return picture with string

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a flash file where I could retrieve a picture by typing a predetermined string via ExternalInterface.

I created an Array of Movieclips but I don't now how to implement a conditional operation to show each one of them by typing a certain string.

Here's my code so far:

```
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    ExternalInterface.addCallback("GetVars",GetVars);

    ExternalInterface.addCallback("Pic","SetPic");

    var myArray:Array = [pic1, pic2]

    function GetVars():Array {
        return [
                     {VariableName:"Pic",DefaultValue:'pic1'},
                ];

    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to type into an HTML input and pass that text into Flash? Or are you typing into Flash and attempting to pass that out to JS and display in HTML. You need to provide more information about what you have provided because it is not clear what your GetVars function is intended to do.

Comment: No, I want to create a swf file that will run on a propriety software with text fields as inputs. The idea is to have a number of pictures and have them show whenever I type it's associated number.